# How to unite hyphenated words in Python and Notepad++ with regex with patterns for exceptions?

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I wonder if you could help me refine the ([^\s\d])(-\s+) (replacement: $1) regex so that it could do the following:

1. It should only join hyphenated words if the letter after the hyphen is a lowercase letter. This means that the second part of the divided word canNOT start with an upper case letter, a punctuation mark, a bracket, a symbol or a number.
2. It should NOT unite hyphenated words where the second part of the divided word is either "és " (and) or "tér " (square). There is a space after each word.

I would like to use the modified regex in both Notepad++ and Python. In the application using Python I can have only a one-line regex (separated by comma) such as ([^\s\d])(-\s+),\1

Example - the following text should remain unchanged after applying the regex.

```
 Nyugat- Németország kormánya
 Text text text Kelet-
 Európa
 Text text text Valéria-
 tér sarok.
 érettségi után a Színház- és 
 Filmművészeti Főiskolára járt
 text text text elválaszt-
 (this is due to OCR errors)
 2001-ben
 8-10
 Szükséges-e
```

Examples for what should be matched:
The original OCR-ed newspaper text:

```
Minden demokrata erőnek közö-
sen kell fellépnie és „falat húznia" 
a Jobbik elé - mondta Ke-
rék-Bánczy Szabolcs, az MDF el-
nökségi tagja keddi sajtótájékoz-
tatóján. Kerék-Bárczy közölte: mi-
közben politikai konszenzus ala-
kult ki a magyar parlamenti pár-
tok között a szlovák nyelvtör-
vénnyel kapcsolatban, pozícióikat 
súlyosan rombolja a Jobbik tevé-
kenysége. Ezt azzal magyarázta, 
hogy a Jobbik állandó hivatkozási 
alapot biztosít a szlovákiai kor-
mánypártoknak. hogy folyamato-
san ujjal mutogathassanak Ma-
gyarországra, mert itt is van egy 
EP-képviselettel rendelkező cso-
port, amely mások kirekesztésére 
és az irredentizmusra építi politi-
káját. Az MDF ezért kezdeménye-
zi, hogy az EP-képviselők nyilvá-
nítsák ki...
```

After applying the regex:

```
Minden demokrata erőnek közösen kell fellépnie és „falat húznia" 
a Jobbik elé - mondta Kerék-Bánczy Szabolcs, az MDF elnökségi tagja 
keddi sajtótájékoztatóján. Kerék-Bárczy közölte: miközben politikai 
konszenzus alakult ki a magyar parlamenti pártok között a szlovák 
nyelvtörvénnyel kapcsolatban, pozícióikat súlyosan rombolja a 
Jobbik tevékenysége. Ezt azzal magyarázta, 
hogy a Jobbik állandó hivatkozási 
alapot biztosít a szlovákiai kormánypártoknak. hogy folyamatosan 
ujjal mutogathassanak Magyarországra, mert itt is van egy
EP-képviselettel rendelkező csoport, amely mások kirekesztésére 
és az irredentizmusra építi politikáját. Az MDF ezért kezdeményezi, 
hogy az EP-képviselők nyilvánítsák ki...
```

Comment: So, what is the pattern you tried? Is it `([^\s\d])(-\s+)`? What is the problem with it?

Comment: Why should the last one `Szükséges-e` be unchanged?

Comment: Yes, I tried that one. The problem with it is that it merges words that it should not. The ones that you can see in the first 8 lines of the provided example.

Comment: Szükséges-e is a form of a question in Hungarian meaning "is it needed?"

Comment: But there is a lowercase char after the `-` and no `és` or `tér` after it. Can this span multiple lines? This will do the replacements except for the last one `([^\s\d])-(?=[a-z])(?!\S*(?:és|tér) )` https://regex101.com/r/lZG6Xg/1

Comment: Yes, but the "és" example is different in the sense that there is a space between the hyphen and the "és". In English, an example would be Media- and Communication Studies.  In Hungarian, we use a hyphen after Media as a kind of abbreviation so that we should not put down Media Studies and Communication Studies.

Comment: What about `([^\W\d_])-\s+(?=(?!(?:és|tér)\b)[a-zàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœ])`? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0CJfTy/1).

Comment: @learner2021 Can you add an example to the question what should match, and why `Szükséges-e` should not match? What do you mean by `(square)`? Is this part of the text `(this is due to OCR errors)` or is it a comment?

Comment: In "Szükséges-e" the "-e" is an indicator of a Yes/No question in English. It occurs in most yes/no questions in Hungarian. That's why we should preserve it as it is. It is more frequent than the "és" and "tér" cases. Square is just the English translation of "tér". (this is due to OCR error) is part of the text. It should not unite words where the second parts starts with a brackert. Under normal circusmtances you do not have such sentences. But I try to clean 100 volumes of OCR-ed newspapers.

Comment: So, doesn't [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/0CJfTy/2) match what you need?

Comment: I added an example for what should match in the original post.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. It works perfectly well!

Comment: Wiktor, just a question for clarification: is àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœ in your regex an attempt to include the special Hungarian chars that are not included in the English alphabet? If so, I need to add some other characters to the list that are missing.

Comment: The correct regex including all special Hungarian chars is ([^\W\d_])-\s+(?=(?!(?:és|tér)\b)[a-záéőúüűöóí])

Comment: You know, you need that for Python only. In Notepad++, you can match any lowercase letter with `[[:lower:]]`

Comment: I posted the answer below with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
([^\W\d_])-\s+(?=(?!(?:és|tér)\b)[a-záéőúüűöóí])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0CJfTy/3). *Details*:

- `([^\W\d_])` - any one letter
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=(?!(?:és|tér)\b)[a-záéőúüűöóí])` - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current location):

  - `(?!(?:és|tér)\b)[a-záéőúüűöóí]` - any char from the `a-záéőúüűöóí` set that is not a starting letter of the `és` or `tér` char sequences that are immediately followed with a word boundary position.